# Desktop icons missing after "logging on" to 13.04

Tags: unity, 13.04, boot, login, icons

So I signed in to my Ubuntu 13.04 (dual booted) computer today and I noticed something strange, the unity lancher had appeared as soon as I signed in, but sign in box has stayed where it is and not disappeared, along with the Ubuntu logo and white dots all over the screen. In addition to this my desktop icons have disappeared.

Any advice as how I could go about getting rid of the login screen and retrieve my icons?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

create a file with that content:

```
#!/bin/bash
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
unity --reset-icons
```

Save it under any name.
Then go to settings of that file (2nd tab) and make it executable, then double click and run it in a terminal.
Keep that file on desktop if it occurs again...

EDIT

to get rid of the login screen you just have to go the the system settings, go to user, and change to automatic login

Comment: Thanks for your answer so quickly! I poked around askubuntu a bit more and found the answer "run nautilus" and it actually worked. I'll try your method if this starts becoming a recurring thing.

Comment: Ok, haven't heard about this solution yet, but good to know. To my answer: I am not sure if dconf is installed by default, one time it worked for me without this line, another time i needed it.